# My app developed with Flutter is reporting a crash on google play. Please check it

Tags: arp, nt

My application, which I developed and published with Flutter, reported a crash on user devices. I don't understand what is causing the problem, what is it and how can I solve this problem?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 21171 >>> com.bsavasy.textrec <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000004e178  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000552798  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2260)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000013990  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000006e58  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336)
  #04  pc 0x00000000002153bc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::getFrame()+52)
  #05  pc 0x000000000021e30c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+404)
  #06  pc 0x000000000022091c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+496)
  #07  pc 0x000000000020f140  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+220)
  #08  pc 0x0000000000230144  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+88)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000015414  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+260)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000014cd8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+412)
  #11  pc 0x00000000000af97c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #12  pc 0x00000000000500d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

My application was single page, I converted it to 2 pages and still could not prevent the lockout.